# Small-Angle Approximation for Cosine

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation

The [small-angle approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation) for cosine is:
$$
\cos (x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}
$$
Question: How can I find a range of values of $x$ for which this approximation gives correct results rounded to 2 decimal places?

Thought: The error term of this $2^{nd}$-order Taylor approximation is
$$
E(x)=\frac{sin(\eta)}{6}x^3,
$$
where $\eta$ is between $x$ and $0$. Thus,
$$
|E(x)|<10^{-2} \to |\sin(\eta)x^3|<6\times10^{-2}.
$$
This is just my thought, but I am not sure this is the correct approach.

Comment: Right. Since $|\eta|<|x|$ you will have $|\sin\eta|\le|\eta|\le |x|$ and you derive a sufficient condition on $x$ from here.

Comment: Observe also that you can think of your approximation as a third order approximation (the series contains only even powers) and use the corresponding error term, which is smaller and gives you a better range for the possible values of $x$.

Comment: @GReyes Thank you. I got the same result as that in Ross Millikan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternating series theorem says the truncation error is smaller than the first neglected term and of the same sign.  The first term you neglect is $\frac {x^4}{4!}$ so we want $$\frac {x^4}{4!} \lt 0.01\\x^4 \lt 0.24\\|x|\lt 0.24^{1/4}\approx 0.700$$
When you demand correct rounding to a number of places it is hard to say what the allowable error is.  If you are very close to a breakpoint you may have to be very accurate.  I used $0.01$ as the allowable error, you can use whatever value you want.

Comment: I never learned about this theorem before. However, I have been able to derive the same result based on @GReyes' comments in the OP. Could you give me a link to the theorem that you used? Thank you.

Comment: It is powerful.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Approximating_sums) has an entry.  If you have an alternating series with the terms decreasing in magnitude, the theorem applies.

Comment: @Just to clarify the answer, the answer should be $x \in (-0.7,0.7)$, right? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I will put absolute value bars on the $x$ in the last line.  Thanks